# Android: Unable to open dialog window / trigger touch event

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a tab fragment on which I am loading a layout. This layout contains a button with an event handler but seems the event is never triggered.

```
public class SettingsFragmentTab extends Fragment
{
    private Button mPickTime;



    private int mHour;
private int mMinute;

static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_list_content, container, false);

    mPickTime = (Button) frame.findViewById(R.id.pickTime);

    // add a click listener to the button
    mPickTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

        return frame;
}

// the callback received when the user "sets" the time in the dialog
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mHour = hourOfDay;
            mMinute = minute;

        }
};
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="right" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/schedule"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
             android:gravity="center_vertical"
             android:text="Schedule"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:textSize="20dp" />


         <Button
             android:id="@+id/pickTime"
             android:layout_width="50dp"
             android:layout_height="50dp"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@id/schedule"
             android:background="@drawable/addtime"
             android:gravity="right" />


         <ListView
             android:id="@+id/listSettings"
             android:layout_width="150dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_above="@id/app_name_tv"
             android:layout_below="@id/pickTime"
             android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
             android:dividerHeight="15.0sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="164dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timezone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Select Your Timezone: "
                 />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timezone"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/timezone"
            android:textAppearance="@drawable/spinner_style" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I have been looking at the code over and over again, but cannot seem to find the issue why the button "mPickTime" 's event not getting triggered.

Comment: I would try putting something like `finish()` in the code instead of, or just after `getActivity.showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID)`, just to make sure thats where you are going wrong

Comment: i have tried to put a breakpoint inside the event handler and also tried to print a toast message. either of the cases the event handler is never triggered.